# Given a mesh, a point on the mesh, a direction and a distance, compute the face+barycentric coordinates of point at that geodesic distance

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I am a beginner at graphics. I am given a triangular mesh (assume a manifold mesh). I want to sample a square on a mesh that is independent of the triangulation.

I am following these steps

- Sample a triangle (based on the areas of the triangles)
- Sample a point uniformly on the triangle
- Sample a random direction

Now all corners of the square can be computed using that point as the origin (and the direction as the x-axis) on a 2D plane trivially. I want to get (Face, barycentric coordinates) of corners of the square on the mesh efficiently (preferably in C++/python) since I'll need to sample a random square again and again. I am looking at libraries such as [Polyscope](https://polyscope.run/structures/surface_mesh/distance_quantities/) or [pygeodesic](https://pypi.org/project/pygeodesic/) that use the heat method to compute the geodesic distance between vertices of the mesh, but I am not sure how to get points at an arbitrary geodesic distance from another point.